# How to write test class for this trigger?

Tags: trigger, code-coverage

```
trigger CheckOrderAttachmentTrigger on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {
    try { 
        Map<Id,Opportunity> opportunityAttachments = new Map<Id,Opportunity>(
            [SELECT Id,(SELECT Id FROM Attachments) FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new]          
        );

        for(Opportunity opp:Trigger.new) {    
            if(opp.StageName=='Order' && // If it is changing to closed/won...
               (!opportunityAttachments.containsKey(opp.id) || // And the opportunity was not found (Insert)...                
                opportunityAttachments.get(opp.id).Attachments == null ||// Or the opportunity attachment list was null...               
                opportunityAttachments.get(opp.id).Attachments.size()==0)) { // Or the attachment list has no entries...                  
                    opp.StageName.addError('Please attach Order form in Notes & Attachment section before changing opportunity stage to Order.'); // So we prevent saving here.                   
                }            
        }
    } catch(exception e) {
        System.assert(e.getMessage().contains('expected message'), 'message=' + e.getMessage());        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Need to Write like this..

```
@isTest
public class CheckOrderAttachmentTriggerTest
{
Static TestMethod void CheckOrderAttachment()
{
    Account acct = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
    insert acct;

    Opportunity om = new Opportunity(Name = 'Name', AccountId = acct.Id, StageName = 'CLosed Won', CloseDate = System.today());
    insert om;

    System.assertEquals(om.name, 'Name');

    Attachment attach = new Attachment();     
    attach.Name = 'Unit Test Attachment';
    Blob bodyBlob = Blob.valueOf('Unit Test Attachment Body');
    attach.body = bodyBlob;
    attach.parentId = om.id;
    insert attach;  

    List<attachment> att1 = [select id, name from Attachment where parent.id =: om.id];
    System.assertEquals(1, att1.size());
}    
}
```

Comment: SFDC Developer - Trigger.New does not show Id value and its important, because it will never get in the Trigger while execution..

Comment: yes i know, question is how to write a test class for trigger, so i have give sample code here, i am not saying that this an exact answer to above trigger.